# Could you explain the parameters "gain" and "reference" in the sox effect "loudness <gain> <reference>"?

Tags: sox

**SUMMARY:**

1. I'd like to use the "loudness" effect in sox to set thirty mp3 files
(containing songs) to the **same loudness**, before I burn them to CD. This is so
that when my friend plays them, he doesn't have to keep adjusting the volume
control when some songs are quieter/louder.

2. The entry for the "loudness" effect in "man sox" is

loudness [gain [reference]]

I've shown the full "man" entry in "Full Details" below.

3. a) But it doesn't explain properly what the "gain" parameter does, or how you
would decide what value to use, or what the difference is between a positive and
negative value,

b) As for "reference", I don't understand what this is or what it does. What
is the significance of 65dB? Why is it positive and not negative? How do I know
what value to choose if I don't want 65dB?

c) If I choose to accept the default value for JUST ONE of the parameters
("gain" or "reference"), do I still need to specify BOTH parameters; otherwise
if I specify ONE parameter, "loudness" won't know which parameter it is.

d) Am I right in thinking that a typical command would look like the following:

```
sox infile outfile loudness -1 65
```

Does -1 stand for -1dB, and does 65 stand for +65dB?

4. **My Questions are:**

a) Please could you answer my questions at "3.", and also explain the things I
don't understand at "3."?

b) Could you give me a couple of examples of "loudness <gain> <reference>", and
what the difference is in the results that I would get?

**FULL DETAILS:**

5. The following is the full entry for the "loudness" effect in "man sox":

loudness [gain [reference]]

Loudness control - similar to the gain effect, but provides
equalisation for the human auditory system. See
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness for a detailed description of
loudness.  The gain is adjusted by the given gain parameter (usually negative)
and the signal equalised according to ISO 226 w.r.t. a reference level of
65dB, though an alternative reference level may be given if the original audio
has been equalised for some other optimal level. A default gain of -10dB is
used if a gain value is not given.

Comment: `for f in *.mp3; do sox "$f" "${f%.*}.norm.mp3" gain -n -2; done`, but I think you'll probably want the compander effect too

Comment: @roaima: Many thanks. Unfortunately I'm not sure that "gain -n" does what I want. I've explained why under Peregrino69's answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

To misquote some old guy in an old movie - "This is not the loudness you're looking for" :-)

The command you think to use is for loudness compensation. From your linked Wikipedia page:

> Loudness compensation is intended to make the recorded music sound more natural when played at a lower levels by boosting low frequencies, to which the ear is less sensitive at lower sound pressure levels.

Stereo systems back in the 80s - 90s (at least) used to have a "Loudness" control. When you decrease the level (volume) of the music, you lose frequencies. Pressing "Loudness" button (or twisting the knob) would adjust the balance so that you'd still hear everything the same way you would when playing louder.

What you *actually* want to do is normalize the tracks. From your linked Wikipedia page:

> **Normalization**
>
> Loudness normalization is a specific type of audio normalization that
> equalizes perceived level such that, for instance, commercials do not
> sound louder than television programs.

[Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_normalization) the Wikipedia article describing audio normalization.

How to is explained in [this](https://madskjeldgaard.dk/posts/sox-tutorial-batch-processing) tutorial on using sox to batch process audio files:

> Normalize
>
> To normalize a file in SoX we need to apply the norm effect which only
> takes one parameter which is the sound level to normalize to. A
> reasonable normalization level is -0.1 dB so let us use that in our
> conversion process.
>
> `for file in *.wav; do sox "$file" "n_$file" norm -0.1; done`
>
> Notice that what we do here is non-destructive. The normalized files
> produced by this process have the same file names as the input files
> but with a “n_” at the beginning to signify that it has been
> normalized.

Peak normalization adjusts the sound in a way that the highest peaks of the audio are normalized at the same level. -0.1dB - -0.5dB is quite common. That can work with material that's already heavily compressed but a more dynamic audio basically requires adding a compressor and/or a limiter to shave down the highest peaks. RMS normalization is another way, the peak levels are averaged and the level is adjusted according to the average level.

The NKOTB is [Loudness Normalization](https://www.sweetwater.com/insync/what-is-lufs-and-why-should-i-care/), briefly touched in Wikipedia's Audio Normalization article. It came into being late 2010s, and during the past couple of years basically all streaming platforms and broadcasters have adopted it as the current standard. Unlike with Peak- and RMS normalization it also takes into account how the listener's perception of the sound changes as the piece of music is playing.

The key term is LUFS, Loudness Units Full Scale, still measured in dB. Loudness level is measured as Momentary (self-evident), Short Term (5 sec) and Integrated (from start to end). Short Term and especially Momentary levels can fluctuate wildly, the most important is the Integrated level. Two pieces of music can be very different, but as long as their Integrated level is the same at the end of the piece, they are perceived equally loud. For example Spotify normalizes everything to -14dB.

A good freeware tool is [Youlean Loudness Meter](https://youlean.co/youlean-loudness-meter/). Both standalone and plugin versions exist. Standalone version works directly on files. Their website also has an online version.

I admit being biased. There are also other good tools, both free and paid. I own a few. However I paid for Youlean's Pro version, as whatever I start with I always end up running it anyway. The only practical difference between the versions is that Pro has a lot more target options both for different streaming services and especially different international broadcasting companies.

Comment: Not to mention a lot easier to grasp than the lengthy "basics of sound theory" -posting I originally wrote :-D Nothing wrong with the command you gave, tho, as gain -n option is a valid alternative to norm :-)

Comment: @Peregrino69: Many many thanks. Forgive me if I'm wrong, but I've a feeling that the sox effect "norm" is not what I want. It's the same as "gain -n", which says "the -n option  normalises the audio to 0dB". But I believe this is PEAK normalisation, not RMS normalisation.

So each file I run it on will just put the highest peak at 0dB. But to get the effect that all the files sound as loud as each other, I believe I need to use RMS normalisation (or a similar averaging method).

That's why I thought that sox's "loudness" would have the desired effect.

Comment: Understandable misconception, and I'm pretty sure you're right. Peak compression can work for material that's already [heavily compressed](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/_qYdpcibE0_w/RtA92YmFsBI/AAAAAAAAALI/57xm8JJNZDI/s400/wave.jpg) but a few tracks with more dynamics end up with huge differences. Experience speaking :-D RMS normalization would be better, but it can be somewhat complicated, IMO obv, and the results easily "about there". Updating my answer.